# In View Pager show the same images to fetch the JSON URL in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I am doing View Pager for sliding images, but View Pages are displaying same images repeatedly and to get index value correctly from JSON URL Images.
It can fetch only last index of images displaying repeatedly.I don't know what I did mistake only last index of images only displaying in my view pager.

Code:

```
ViewPager viewPager;
private ZoomAdapter adapter;
String oneimg;
String singlepro, multipleimg, productpaths, sellers;
ArrayList<ZoomimageModel> imgs;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adlist;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
// ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adlist
public static final String TAG_IMAGE = "original_res";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoomproduct_);
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.b2)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.b2)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.b2)
            .build();


    /********************  this is for single page product ***********************/

    Intent singleproductpage = getIntent();
    singlepro = singleproductpage.getStringExtra("currentinedx");
    Intent multipleimages = getIntent();
    multipleimg = multipleimages.getStringExtra("multipleimages");
    Intent productpath = getIntent();
    productpaths = productpath.getStringExtra("productpath");
    Intent seller = getIntent();
    sellers = seller.getStringExtra("sellerid");
    //  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Zoomproduct_Activity.this);
    //   pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    //   pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    singleproduct();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ZoomAdapter(Zoomproduct_Activity.this, imgs);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void singleproduct() {


    String productpath = productpaths;
    String sid = sellers;
    String cindex = singlepro;
    int cindexs = Integer.parseInt(cindex);
    String multiimg = multipleimg;
    JSONArray multipleimage = null;
    JSONArray singleimages = null;
    try {
        multipleimage = new JSONArray(multiimg);
        singleimages = new JSONArray(multiimg);


        horizontalimage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        // final RelativeLayout r1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_border);
        //   frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
        ii = new ImageView[multipleimage.length()];
        ZoomimageModel zoom = new ZoomimageModel();

        imgs = new ArrayList<ZoomimageModel>();
        adlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        if (singleimages.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < singleimages.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject singleimg = multipleimage.getJSONObject(i);
                String oneimg = singleimg.getString("original_res");
                String singleiamges = productpath + sid + '/' + oneimg;
                       /*map.put(TAG_IMAGE,singleiamges);
                       adlist.add(map);*/
                zoom.setImageUrl(singleiamges);
                imgs.add(zoom);
                String ad = String.valueOf(adlist);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ad, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(ad, "show");

            }

        }


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ZoomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflator;
    ImageView imgDisplay;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ZoomimageModel> slideShowImages;

    DisplayImageOptions options;

    public ZoomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ZoomimageModel> slideShowImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.slideShowImages = slideShowImages;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.slip1)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.b2)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slideShowImages.size();
    }

    // @Override
          /*  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == ((ImageView) object);
            }*/

    //    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.productzoomrow, container,
                false);
        imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        ZoomimageModel zooms = slideShowImages.get(position);
        System.out.println("ImageUrl---------------------" + slideShowImages.get(position).getImageUrl());
        YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(zooms.getImageUrl(), imgDisplay, options);
        container.addView(viewLayout);
        return viewLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }


          /* @Override
           public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
           {
               ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
           }*/
}
```

Logcat:

```
  -- -- -- -- - beginning of crash
  05 - 06 07: 00: 43.434 15557 - 15557 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.journaldev.navigationdrawer, PID: 15557
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {
      com.journaldev.navigationdrawer / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Activity.Zoomproduct_Activity
  }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Adapter.ZoomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()'
  on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2325)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2387)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1303)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5254)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 903)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 698)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Adapter.ZoomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()'
  on a null object reference
  at com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Activity.Zoomproduct_Activity.singleproduct(Zoomproduct_Activity.java: 198)
  at com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Activity.Zoomproduct_Activity.onCreate(Zoomproduct_Activity.java: 102)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 5990)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1106)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2278)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2387) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 151) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1303) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5254) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 903) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 698)
```

Anyone help glad to appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` (In **singleproduct()** ) before **initializing** ZoomAdapter  (`adapter = new ZoomAdapter(Zoomproduct_Activity.this, imgs);`).

Please call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after initializing ZoomAdapter.

Comment: I already initialized after that only i put adapter.notifysetchangerd(), but doesn't workout for me

Comment: if am not using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); what will happen

Answer (score 0):

replace your line of code with below:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
adapter = new ZoomAdapter(Zoomproduct_Activity.this, imgs);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: @Baba I having a problem displaying only last index of image three or four time.It can fetch index properly, but  displaying only last index of image repeatedly

Comment: API response fine i got all the images from for loop,but i don't know why only last image display in View Pager